# Decrease 2 GB memory footprint of regex/linq or solve get distinct group values otherwise

Tags: c#, .net, regex, performance, linq

I need to compress a very verbatim raw data Format to something more streamlined by extracting certain parts to create a different file format containing a LUT and much shorter datalines.

My Testdata is read from a file, containing about 400k lines - I put in a programmatic way to create data.

For now I am mostly interested in the distinct values of the groups I output. 'ref' and 'ref2' are needed as well, but they are almost unique in itself.

The 'naive' aproach via regex works ... but takes up more than 2 GB of Process Memory and lot's of time - how to optimize the regex or get the distinct values otherwise?

Edit: down to 700MB thanks to [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) hints.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Testdata/Creation:

```
static string[] NAMES1 = "cat,dog,deer,buffalo,lion,mouse,hedgehog".Split(',');
static string[] NAMES2 = "lily,rose,thyme,salt".Split(',');
static string[] TYPES = "1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2".Split(',');

static string MakeText (int n, string[] names)
{
  if (n % 15 == 0)
    return $"{names[n % names.Length]}${n}";
  else if (n % 5 == 0)
    return $"{names[n % names.Length]}${n}${TYPES[n % TYPES.Length]}";
  else
    return $"{names[n % names.Length]}$EGAL${n}${TYPES[n % TYPES.Length]}$MORE";
}

static string CreateData (int rows)
{
  var ids = Enumerable.Range(0,8).Select(n => $"{Guid.NewGuid()}-1234").ToList();
  var id2 = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}-9876";

  Console.WriteLine ($"\nIDs:    {string.Join ("\n    ", ids)}");
  Console.WriteLine ($"\nID 2:   {id2}");
  Console.WriteLine ($"\nNAMES1: {string.Join (", ", NAMES1)}");
  Console.WriteLine ($"\nNAMES2: {string.Join (", ", NAMES2)}");   

  var inOrder =
    Enumerable
    .Range(0, rows/2)
    .Select(n => $"{MakeText(n,NAMES1)}," +
                 $"{ids[ Math.Min(ids.Count-1,n / (rows/2/ids.Count))]}" +
                 $"={MakeText(Math.Min(int.MaxValue,rows*10)-n,NAMES2)},{id2}");

  var outOfOrder =
    Enumerable
    .Range(rows/2, rows)
    .Select(n => $"{MakeText(n,NAMES1)},{ids[n % ids.Count]}" +
                 $"={MakeText(int.MaxValue-n,NAMES2)},{id2}");

  return string.Join (Environment.NewLine, inOrder.Concat (outOfOrder)) 
    + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Using the regex:

```
static void Main (string[] args)
{
  var content= CreateData (400000);

  var r = new Regex( 
    @"^(?<ar>.+?)(\$EGAL)?(\$(?<ref>[0-9]+))(\$(?<typ>[123]))?" + 
    @"(\$MORE)?(,(?<id>.+))"+
    @"=(?<ar2>.+?)(\$EGAL)?(\$(?<ref2>[0-9]+))(\$(?<typ2>[123]))?" + 
    @"(\$MORE)?(,(?<id2>.+))(\r)?$",
    RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.Multiline|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

  var matches = r.Matches(content).OfType<Match>().ToList();

  var ids1 = matches 
    .Select(
      m => m
      .Groups["id"]
      .Captures
      .OfType<Capture>()
      .Select(c=> c.Value)
    )
    .SelectMany(i=>i)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

  Console.WriteLine ($"\nids:    {string.Join ("\n    ", ids1)}");

  var ids2 = matches 
    .Select(
      m => m
      .Groups["id2"]
      .Captures
      .OfType<Capture>()
      .Select(c=> c.Value)
    )
    .SelectMany(i=>i)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

  Console.WriteLine ($"\nid 2:   {string.Join ("\n    ", ids2)}");

  var n1 = matches 
    .Select(
      m => m
      .Groups["ar"]
      .Captures
      .OfType<Capture>()
      .Select(c=> c.Value)
    )
    .SelectMany(i=>i)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

  Console.WriteLine ($"\nnames1: {string.Join (", ", n1)}");

  var n2 = matches 
    .Select(
      m => m
      .Groups["ar2"]
      .Captures
      .OfType<Capture>()
      .Select(c=> c.Value)
    )
    .SelectMany(i=>i)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();

  Console.WriteLine ($"\nnames2: {string.Join (", ", n2)}");

  // need the type's and refs as well to recreate the substituted 
  // datalines after creating the LUT and put them together in some
  // new file - that's easy.
}
```

Comment: If you precise your pattern a bit to [replace `.` with more appropriate subpatterns](https://regex101.com/r/knSux2/1), you may improve the regex performance greatly. Also, run `Regex.Matches` once, store the results in some variable, and reuse it when accessing capture collections.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, not repeating Regex.Matches brought me down from 2GB to 700MB. I'll look into the Sub Patterns.

Comment: Well, with the pattern optimization, it looks like the test contents do not really include all possible types of variations you may have. The main point is still finding more restricted pattern than just `.+?` that is the main performance killer in such scenarios.

Comment: is there a reason you can't just compress the data?

Comment: Matthew: the data contains dead text (like $MORE, $EGAL) that is not needed. Simply zipping it would still need to compress this superflous data, whereby I can eliminate it completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entire contents are parsed in one go, the matches/capture collections probably will always occupy a certain amount of space, that can only be optimized so far. Memory wise it's probably better to handle the lines one at a time and only keep the unique values (e.g. with a `HashSet` ). Personally I like to use the readers from the IO namespace (in this example a `StringReader`, but for existing file other readers can be used)

```
 var r = new Regex( 
    @"^(?<ar>.+?)(\$EGAL)?(\$(?<ref>[0-9]+))(\$(?<typ>[123]))?" + 
    @"(\$MORE)?(,(?<id>.+))"+
    @"=(?<ar2>.+?)(\$EGAL)?(\$(?<ref2>[0-9]+))(\$(?<typ2>[123]))?" + 
    @"(\$MORE)?(,(?<id2>.+))?$",
    RegexOptions.Compiled|RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);

var values= new[]{"ar", "ref", "typ","id", "ar2", "ref2", "typ2", "id2"}.Select((s,i)=> new {Group=s, Index = i + 1, Values = new HashSet<string>()}).ToArray();    
values= values.Where(v=> !v.Group.StartsWith("ref")).ToArray(); //this line is only an addition for testing to not include the ref values
using(var sr = new StringReader(content)){
    string line;
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null){
        var gr = r.Match(line).Groups;
        foreach(var gv in values)
            gv.Values.Add(gr[gv.Index].Value);
    }
}

//output results
foreach(var v in values)
    Console.WriteLine ($"\n{v.Group}s:    {string.Join ("\n    ", v.Values)}");
```

Haven't really touched the regex itself, but the above should parse all unique values with a lower memory footprint. It could be further optimized by using a custom parser for the lines.
(Instead of separate variables, all collections are inside the `values` object)

Comment: After having a sharp look at the usecase I will forgoe this "parse and store in memory for lookup" by simply applying the regex on the (locally cached and compacted) 10MB file any time the user needs that. Even if the regex takes 1s to read the file line by line and find a match inside it this will be better than hogging a lot of memory for the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Sounds good. Don't know the exact usecase, but if the file is already stored in memory, storing find results doesn't have to be as memory intensive as long as the results reference the same data. 
For example the file is stored as a string array of lines and the buffered result stores a reference to those lines (not the regex matches). That's just guessing though. (If the file is not buffered, a FileReader instead of a StringReader can be used directly on the file for lowest memory consumption). (ps it may always be possible to parse directly instead of regex for optimal performance)